# VSCode. Как удалить проект из VSC, но не удалять его из компьютера?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить проект из VSCode так, чтобы файлы, папки исчезали ТОЛЬКО из VSCode, но на компьютере оставались для возможности вернуться к этому проекту в будущем? На текущий момент получается удалить только безвозвратно отовсюду. Возможно неправильно подключаю изначально?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "удалить проект из VSCode"? Можно, конечно, удалить папку .vscode из проекта, эту удалит настройки vscode для этой папки, но никак не помешает снова открыть этот же проект в vscode опять. Сам проект никак в VSCode не "хранится", удалять из VSCode нечего.

Comment: При перетаскивании проекта в Рабочую зону, его название отображается в САМОЙ РАБОЧЕЙ ОБЛАСТИ. И впоследствие просто убрать название временно ненужного проекта из РАБОЧЕЙ ОБЛАСТИ невозможно. Мне приходится удалять проект. И он, при этом удаляется и из компьютера. Как избежать удаление проекта из компьютера - удалить его название только из рабочей области ?

Comment: Делайте клик правой кнопкой по папке в рабочей области, выбираете "удалить папку из рабочей области"

Comment: Вы можете нажать `CTRL + R` и удалить от туда путь нажав на крестик.